# Can you clarify these terminologies?

Tags: machine-learning

I am having confusion with the terminology *Computational Intelligence*.

As far as I know: *Computational intelligence* refers to the field of study that combines principles from artificial intelligence, machine learning, and optimization to develop algorithms and models capable of solving complex problems and adapting to changing environments.

What is the difference between *Machine Learning* and *Computational Intelligence*? Are they related or not?

What are **not** the sub-fields or sub-topics of *Computational Intelligence*?

Where does Computational Intelligence sit in the [following chart](https://medium.com/@devin_chandula/understanding-the-ai-basic-hierarchy-b9d7438bff91)?

[image]